# How to change command line prompt name and add path of current directory after name?

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

Currently my command line prompt looks like this `nuve@nuve-Inspiron-5547:~$` but I want to change it `Azer's Terminal:"Path of current directory"`. How can I do this? I need exact code line to add to bashrc file.

Comment: There's an answer to the linked question which shows exactly how to put the current working directory at the end of the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step ;

1. Open the terminal
2. If you don't have a `.bashrc` file in your `$HOME` (`/home/<username>`) , make it with type this command `touch $HOME/.bashrc`
3. If you have it, open it with text editor like nano, etc.
4. add this script in your .bashrc

   ```
   PS1='[ \h \W]\$ '
   ```
5. To make your hostname such as you want open file `/etc/hostname` with `sudo`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hostname
   ```
6. Remove previous hostname and add new hostname which you want in this file

   ```
   Azer's Terminal
   ```
7. If you have finish , logout or reboot your system to make it affect .

This my .bashrc file [image]